# Animate div background position on slide change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**DEMO**](http://www.dev.devncode.com/blurtest/#1)

**GOAL:** Blur div stays in place on slide change but the background image should animate.

[image]
The blur is part of each specific slide, which is why it moves when the slide rotates. I need to keep the blur in place while the text & background image slides.

Here is my structure:

```
<div class="slider" id="slides">
    <ul class="slides-container" >
        <li>
            <img src="img/bg.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="bg blur" style="background-image:url(img/bg.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="copy">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, fuga laborum autem sit facere corrupti quis voluptatibus suscipit facilis aliquid quae vel illum delectus hic, laudantium debitis at error impedit.</p>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="img/transformer.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="bg blur" style="background-image:url(img/transformer.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="copy">
                <h1>Something Else</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, fuga laborum autem sit facere corrupti quis voluptatibus suscipit facilis aliquid quae vel illum delectus hic, laudantium debitis at error impedit.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="controls slides-navigation">
        <a href="#" class="prev"><</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">></a>
    </div>

</div><!-- end slider -->
```

this creates the copied image blur

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: url('../img/blur.svg#blur'); /* for Firefox */
    clip: rect(0px, 440px, 1000px, 0px);
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

I am using a JS slider plugin too achieve the slider.

```
$('#slides').superslides({
    slide_speed: 800,
    pagination: false,
    hashchange: true,
    scrollable: true,
    play: 5000
});
```

I am guessing I would need to

1. Make the blur a separate div outside the slider.
2. Animate the BLUR background-position-x property.

I am just not excatly sure how too accomplish this.. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Start by moving the blur div out of the slider element, or else it will definitely slide with everything else.

In your demo, it looks like it's safe to say that the blur div will always be located on the top left corner of the window viewport, is that correct? If that's the case, it's as easy as using position: absolute to position the blur there.

Note: You'll want a contain div with position: relative; in order to absolutely position your blur div relative to that.

So something like:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  /* All your other blur styling here. */
}
```

By default, the .blur element should be absolutely positioned top: 0 left: 0 which is where you want it. You can always adjust it's position using top, left, bottom, right.

Comment: Yes but my question is, how do I go about animating the background position of the blur when the slider changes?